# Gradle DSL method not found: 'dataBinding()'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am new to Android. Here I am trying to add data binding to my android app for that I enabled data binding to true in-app level gradle file but the problem is it's not syncing it gives some error like this.

```
Gradle DSL method not found: 'dataBinding()'
Possible causes:
The project 'TriviaApp' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.4.1 and sync project

The project 'TriviaApp' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

> this is My app level gradle file code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.triviaapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding(
            enabled: true
    )
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Can anyone please help me to figure out what am I doing wrong and help me to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

Make sure, your **build.gradle** is

```
    dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        }

   allprojects {
       repositories {
        jcenter()
       }
    }
```